# Php string explode string based on characters match with string condition

Tags: php, arrays, regex, explode

I have strings like this:

```
$string1 = '35 Hose & Couplings/350902 GARDEN HOSE COUPLING, PVC, 16\/19 MM"';

$string2 = '35 Hose & Couplings/350904 GARDEN HOSE TAP CONNECTOR, PVC, 3\/4" FEMALE THREAD"';
```

I tried to separate the string and turn it into  an array like this:

```
$name1 = explode('/', $string1);
$name1 = trim(end($name1));
$name2 = explode('/', $string2);
$name2 = trim(end($name2));

/*
 #results
 $name1[0] = '35 Hose & Couplings';
 $name1[1] = '350902 GARDEN HOSE COUPLING, PVC, 16\';
 $name1[2] = '19 MM"';
 ...
 #expected results
 $name1[0] = '35 Hose & Couplings';
 $name1[1] = '350902 GARDEN HOSE COUPLING, PVC, 16\/19 MM"';
 ...
*/
```

I want to explode the string when there is `/` only, but when it meets `\/` it ***shouldn't*** explode the string, my code still explode the string if it contains `\/`, is there a way to do this?

Comment: 'i want to explode the string when there is '/' only, but when it meets '/' it will not explode the string'- what do you mean ?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Yes that's what i want

Comment: have you looked at preg_split (http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: I think this is a job for regex, unfortunately my regex skills suck. Maybe you could try looking here for further assistance until someone can provide better guidance https://regexr.com/

Comment: You an either first "protect" the exception "\\/" by replacing it with some "magical" sequence and convert it back after having replaced the remaining "/" occurrances, or you use a regular expression with lookahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with negative look-behind:

```
$parts = preg_split('~(?<!\\\\)/~', $string1);
```

See example on [eval.in](https://eval.in/963036)

Comment: I like that solution. It does the job and the regex looks like a fish.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a live demo in  your answer.

Comment: @revo, as far as I know SO does not have possibilities for live PHP demos within answers -- as exists for JavaScript. But I added a link.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mean the other way either.

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this:

```
$string1 = str_replace("\/","@",$string1);
$name1 = explode('/', $string1);
foreach($name1 as $id => $name) {
    $name1[$id] = str_replace("@","\/",$name1[$id]);
}
```

a little cumbersome, I know, but should do the trick. Wrap it in a function for better readability.

Basically I replaced the string you do not want to explode by with a temporary string and reverted it back after exploding.

Comment: Then use something else, like # or whatever. Code needs to be adjusted to a project, always.

Comment: You are right, I copied that code fragment from the question. I removed it now.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek it prints `350902 GARDEN HOSE COUPLING, PVC, 16@19 MM"` the **@** is replacing the **\/** , there'll be a problem if i want to use **@**

Comment: Yes, it was suggested above, I advised to use "#" or whatever sign you will not need instead. The foreach loop should revert @ back to \/.

Comment: Although I believe regex is the way forward with this; you could also user multiple symbols that you would never have in sequence. `@#]!` for example...

Comment: @IsThisJavascript that wouldn't work, because you explode by one of them, so the sequence is irrelevant.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek Was just a suggestion so that the OP doesn't have to reserve a `@` specific character. It would work aswell, not sure why you think it wouldnt

Comment: You are right, I was so focused on exploding I forgot the OP wouldn't risk exploding by the replacement. My bad. Your suggestion is more replacement-proof.